# Geotools JAI fatjar causing problems in native dependencies

Tags: scala, jar, sbt-assembly, geotools, jai

I have a scala project using geotools / JAI dependencies in order to process ESRi ASCII Grid files to WKT in java. When deploying a fat-jar, I get a SIGSEV in the native part of the jai code.

It is using the following dependencies:

```
lazy val geotools = "17.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.geotools" % "gt-main" % geotools,
  "org.geotools" % "gt-arcgrid" % geotools,
  "org.geotools" % "gt-process-raster" % geotools)
```

When creating a fat jar like:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) =>
    xs match {
      // Concatenate everything in the services directory to keep GeoTools happy.
      case ("services" :: _ :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.concat
      // Concatenate these to keep JAI happy.
      case ("javax.media.jai.registryFile.jai" :: Nil) | ("registryFile.jai" :: Nil) | ("registryFile.jaiext" :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.concat
      case (name :: Nil) => {
        // Must exclude META-INF/*.([RD]SA|SF) to avoid "Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes" exception.
        if (name.endsWith(".RSA") || name.endsWith(".DSA") || name.endsWith(".SF")) {
          MergeStrategy.discard
        }
        else {
          MergeStrategy.deduplicate
        }
      }
      case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
    }
  case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
}
```

One of JAIS JNI native C dependencies blows up with a SIGSEV. When instead simply using the (a lot unsafer `MergeStrategy.first`) like:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  // TODO bad strategy, find out why below does not work.
  case PathList("org", "datasyslab", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.singleOrError
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("META-INF", "MANIFEST.MF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

The code works without SIGSEV. When looking at the logs of `MergeStrategy.SingleOrError`, I cant figure out what is the dependency causing the problems in the native code:

```
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-coverage/jars/gt-coverage-17.0.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jai
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.jaitools/jt-zonalstats/jars/jt-zonalstats-1.4.0.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jai
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-process-raster/jars/gt-process-raster-17.0.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jai
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.jaitools/jt-rangelookup/jars/jt-rangelookup-1.4.0.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jai
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.jaitools/jt-contour/jars/jt-contour-1.4.0.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jai
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.jaitools/jt-vectorize/jars/jt-vectorize-1.4.0.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jai
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.affine/jt-affine/jars/jt-affine-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale/jt-scale/jars/jt-scale-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.vectorbin/jt-vectorbin/jars/jt-vectorbin-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.translate/jt-translate/jars/jt-translate-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.algebra/jt-algebra/jars/jt-algebra-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandmerge/jt-bandmerge/jars/jt-bandmerge-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandselect/jt-bandselect/jars/jt-bandselect-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandcombine/jt-bandcombine/jars/jt-bandcombine-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.border/jt-border/jars/jt-border-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.buffer/jt-buffer/jars/jt-buffer-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.crop/jt-crop/jars/jt-crop-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.mosaic/jt-mosaic/jars/jt-mosaic-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.lookup/jt-lookup/jars/jt-lookup-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.nullop/jt-nullop/jars/jt-nullop-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.rescale/jt-rescale/jars/jt-rescale-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.stats/jt-stats/jars/jt-stats-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.warp/jt-warp/jars/jt-warp-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.zonal/jt-zonal/jars/jt-zonal-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.binarize/jt-binarize/jars/jt-binarize-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.format/jt-format/jars/jt-format-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.colorconvert/jt-colorconvert/jars/jt-colorconvert-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.errordiffusion/jt-errordiffusion/jars/jt-errordiffusion-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.orderdither/jt-orderdither/jars/jt-orderdither-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.colorindexer/jt-colorindexer/jars/jt-colorindexer-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.imagefunction/jt-imagefunction/jars/jt-imagefunction-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.piecewise/jt-piecewise/jars/jt-piecewise-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.classifier/jt-classifier/jars/jt-classifier-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.rlookup/jt-rlookup/jars/jt-rlookup-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/registryFile.jaiext
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/javax.media/jai_imageio/jars/jai_imageio-1.1.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageInputStreamSpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.imageio-ext/imageio-ext-streams/jars/imageio-ext-streams-1.1.17.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageInputStreamSpi
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/javax.media/jai_imageio/jars/jai_imageio-1.1.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageOutputStreamSpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.imageio-ext/imageio-ext-streams/jars/imageio-ext-streams-1.1.17.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageOutputStreamSpi
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/javax.media/jai_imageio/jars/jai_imageio-1.1.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.imageio-ext/imageio-ext-tiff/jars/imageio-ext-tiff-1.1.17.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.imageio-ext/imageio-ext-arcgrid/jars/imageio-ext-arcgrid-1.1.17.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/javax.media/jai_imageio/jars/jai_imageio-1.1.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.imageio-ext/imageio-ext-tiff/jars/imageio-ext-tiff-1.1.17.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.imageio-ext/imageio-ext-arcgrid/jars/imageio-ext-arcgrid-1.1.17.jar:META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/javax.media/jai_imageio/jars/jai_imageio-1.1.jar:META-INF/services/javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/it.geosolutions.jaiext.crop/jt-crop/jars/jt-crop-1.0.13.jar:META-INF/services/javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.jaitools/jt-zonalstats/jars/jt-zonalstats-1.4.0.jar:META-INF/services/javax.media.jai.OperationsRegistrySpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-process-raster/jars/gt-process-raster-17.0.jar:META-INF/services/javax.media.jai.OperationsRegistrySpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.jaitools/jt-rangelookup/jars/jt-rangelookup-1.4.0.jar:META-INF/services/javax.media.jai.OperationsRegistrySpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.jaitools/jt-contour/jars/jt-contour-1.4.0.jar:META-INF/services/javax.media.jai.OperationsRegistrySpi
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.jaitools/jt-vectorize/jars/jt-vectorize-1.4.0.jar:META-INF/services/javax.media.jai.OperationsRegistrySpi
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-main/jars/gt-main-17.0.jar:META-INF/services/org.geotools.filter.FunctionFactory
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-process/jars/gt-process-17.0.jar:META-INF/services/org.geotools.filter.FunctionFactory
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-main/jars/gt-main-17.0.jar:META-INF/services/org.geotools.util.ConverterFactory
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-process-raster/jars/gt-process-raster-17.0.jar:META-INF/services/org.geotools.util.ConverterFactory
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-main/jars/gt-main-17.0.jar:META-INF/services/org.opengis.filter.expression.Function
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-coverage/jars/gt-coverage-17.0.jar:META-INF/services/org.opengis.filter.expression.Function
[error] /Users/geoheil/.ivy2/cache/org.geotools/gt-cql/jars/gt-cql-17.0.jar:META-INF/services/org.opengis.filter.expression.Function
```

and here the sigsev information

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd780b9bfe1, pid=21657, tid=0x00007f0674c4a700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x8a4fe1]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/vagrant/development/projects/HybridAccess/spark/hs_err_pid21657.log
Compiled method (c1) 6599346 22508   !   3       java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue::take (203 bytes)
total in heap  [0x00007fd76bda5b90,0x00007fd76bda83a8] = 10264
relocation     [0x00007fd76bda5cb8,0x00007fd76bda5eb8] = 512
main code      [0x00007fd76bda5ec0,0x00007fd76bda7360] = 5280
stub code      [0x00007fd76bda7360,0x00007fd76bda7508] = 424
metadata       [0x00007fd76bda7508,0x00007fd76bda7560] = 88
scopes data    [0x00007fd76bda7560,0x00007fd76bda7d80] = 2080
scopes pcs     [0x00007fd76bda7d80,0x00007fd76bda8170] = 1008
dependencies   [0x00007fd76bda8170,0x00007fd76bda8188] = 24
handler table  [0x00007fd76bda8188,0x00007fd76bda8308] = 384
nul chk table  [0x00007fd76bda8308,0x00007fd76bda83a8] = 160
```

And the links I have found for maven:
JAI dependencies in geotools are hard deploy as a single fat jar (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app, http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Building-runnable-jar-file-td4320365.html).

Comment: Ever make are progress on this? Having the same issue.

Comment: General: fixed when the configuration files in meta folder are handled correctly in case of a stand alone jvm application. However, in my case this did not work as i.e. Nifi or sparks class loader were doing something different and the configuration properties of geotools were not correctly available on the class path. Ended up reimplementing the desired algorithms without jai. Turns out this is faster as a single file is not larger than ram I.e. Only a large number of small files (up to 30 MB) exists.

Comment: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app